# Mifare keyfobs reader returns different values

Tags: hex, rfid, mifare, reader, wiegand

I have a wiegand26 RFID reader that returns a value of 13711284. But the clients reader shows 6ECBD718.

I have already tried to reverse the bits and inverting them as well, but to no success.

I'm not really sure if the problem lies in some kind of conversion between the two results or if there is some other problem that is causing the difference.